# Use CountVectorizer with file where every line is a document

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a **huge** file where I want to treat every line as a document and use CountVectorizer to create the vectors.

What I have tried so far:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input='file', decode_error='ignore', strip_accents='unicode')
corpus = open('corpus.txt')
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform([corpus]).toarray()
print vectors
print vectorizer.vocabulary_
```

The file corpus.txt

```
Human machine interface for lab abc computer applications
A survey of user opinion of computer system response time
The EPS user interface management system
```

*What I expect is to get an array with three vectors*. Instead I get an array with one vector:

```
[[1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2]]
{u'lab': 7, u'eps': 3, u'applications': 1, u'management': 9, u'user': 17, u'human': 5, u'interface': 6, u'response': 12, u'abc': 0, u'for': 4, u'of': 10, u'system': 14, u'machine': 8, u'computer': 2, u'survey': 13, u'time': 16, u'opinion': 11, u'the': 15}
```

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

Careful, from the documentation the `input=file` argument to CountVectorizer has:

> If ‘file’, the sequence items must have a ‘read’ method (file-like object) that is called to fetch the bytes in memory.

The read method called on a file will read the entire text as a single string into memory.  So with `[corpus]` you get a single string representing the entire text of your file.

Why not do the following instead?

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(decode_error='ignore',strip_accents='unicode')
corpus = open('corpus.txt')
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
```

You can just pass the file handle `corpus` directly to fit since fit accepts an iterator. That should allow you to build the vectorizer without reading the entire file into memory.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing it the whole file. If you want to do it line by line you need a loop that passes one row at a time into the CV and returns one vector. You still use just the one CV object just call fit_transform multiple times.

Alternatively you can read it into a pandas dataframe and then use apply but probably the timing will be similar.

Comment: This will create vectors with different length for each document. Also, they won't share the same vocabulary.

Comment: That is true but then you can turn each vector into a pandas series with term as index. Then after the loop you can use pd.concat and it will match them up for you.

Answer (score 0):

Modified code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input='file', decode_error='ignore', strip_accents='unicode')
corpus = open('corpus.txt')
docs = corpus.split("\n") 
vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(docs)
print vectors
print vectorizer.vocabulary_
```

This line `docs = corpus.split("\n")` divides your corpus into separate documents until the split function does not get newline.